# Android SyncAdapter and concurrent write accesses

Tags: android-syncadapter, database-concurrency

I am developing a RESTful Android app using SyncAdapter. I have watched some screencasts and read some tutorials, but they only address basic dynamics. Before starting to write the code, I would like to try and receive feedback from expert users about concurrency issues.

Step 1. The user `U` inserts a new entry `E` into the table `T` of the database. The entry has a column `status = TO_SYNC`.

Step 2. Before the entry `E` is synced, `U` decides to modify it. An activity `A` starts for modifying the column values of `E`.

Step 3. While the user is modifying the entry, the SyncAdapter starts and sends the entries with `status == TO_SYNC` to the server. For each entry, the `SyncAdapter` sets `status = SYNCED` once it receives a positive answer from the server.

Step 4. Let's say that a concurrent access to the same entry `E` causes a conflict:

1. The SyncAdapter reads `E`, sends `E` to the server
2. The activity `A` completes and sets `E` status to `TO_SYNC`
3. The SyncAdapter receives the ok from the server and sets the `status` of `E` to `SYNCED`
4. At this point the new values of `E` will not be synced since the value `TO_SYNC` has been overwritten by the SyncAdapter.

My question is: how can I avoid such issue without blocking the entire database with a `begin/end transaction` while syncing (which could take a long time to complete)? Should I fall back on a classical java lock on single entries? Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync to the server based on timestamps (call it `LAST_UPDATED_TIME`) rather than a simple flag and along with that in another column (call it `HASH`) you store the hash value of the concatenated string of all the values in a row. With this you check the timestamp since last sync, get those incremental data to be synced and sync to the server (of course in a separate thread) and when you get back the results you will do the following steps:

- Compare the hash of the data currently in the database/row against what was synced.
- Based on the truthness of the above statement two things can happen:

  1. If the hash of the data in the db/row is equals to that value that was synced, you just update the `LAST_UPDATED_TIME` field with the time of sync
  2. If the hash of the data in the db/row is not equals to that values that was synced, you immediately sync the row again (you can obviously optimize this even more)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, with second column "updated_at"

1. The SyncAdapter reads E, sends E to the server
2. The activity A completes and sets E status to TO_SYNC and updated_at at NOW
3. The SyncAdapter receives the ok from the server
4. The SyncAdapter reads E_bis, compare E.updated_at and E_bis.updated_at, if different => request new sync, else => sets the status of E to SYNCED